# Wrong graph displayed using \addplot command (Tikz package)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I've been using the \addplot command to draw several functions in a \tikzpicture environment. The first 2 graphs were fine but somehow the other ones gave weird things that did not match the respective function.

For example the following code was used for a cubic function, and the graph showed at least 5 turning points for some reason.

```
\addplot[domain=-10:10, smooth, red]{2x^3 - x^2 + 8x - 6};
```

Does this have to do with me having several graphs and not "flusing inputs" (if that's a thing in LaTeX, I'm new to the \tikz and \pgfplots packages)? If not, what's wrong with my code? Any help appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: If you ask "What is wrong with my code?", you have to give a MWE (Minimal Working Example), not a code snippet.

Comment: Multiplication has be input explicitly: `2*x^3 - x^2 + 8*x - 6`